# Check if line is lying inside of polygon

Tags: geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

In my problem I have an conveyor belt on which a piece of luggage is moving in counterclockwise direction (so left is inside every time when moving alongside the luggage). I know have a line that is possibly lying inside of the conveyor belt. The conveyor belt is modelled by lines with their start and end point as well as the line to check is. The starting point of the line to check is equal to the starting point of one of the conveyor belt's lines (conveyor belt is a simple polygon). My approach was to check if the clockwise angle around this point (starting from the line being part of the conveyor belt) is greater than 180 degrees (than it would be inside) but that doesn't work for all cases. I can minimize the number of failures by laying the line alongside the previous starting point (of the previous line of the conveyor belt) but there are still some cases where this doesn't work.

Thanks for your help, I'll provide any further information needed if I can.

EDIT:
It would work for the following with alpha being 333 degrees but beta only 171; the blue line is thus outside of the (black) conveyor belt:[image]

However it wouldn't work for other examples. Imagine the upper part of this image on the right side, too (would look like a castle then ;), a line starting from the blue right point to the then upper right hand corner (would be coordinate (3,2)), would have an alpha value less than 180 (145) and thus it would be considered lying outside though it is actually inside.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want to check whether a line segment lies entirely inside an arbitrary polygon.

First transform the line segment to make it `(0, 0)-(L, 0)`; this takes a translation and rotation (you can also scale to `(0, 0)-(1, 0)`); apply the same transform to the polygon.

Find all intersections of the polygon edges with the X axis (they are detected by the condition `Yi > 0 != Yi+1 > 0`). If there's any intersection such that `0 < X < L`, report false. Otherwise, report true if the number of intersections such that `X < 0` is odd.

There are degenerate cases with `Yi=0`, `X=0` or `X=L`. It is up to you to decide if "inside" holds or not in such cases before you can adjust the algorithm to handle them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having a look at the **Determining if a point lies on the interior of a polygon** on [Paul Bourke's amazing website](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonmesh/).

[image: point in poly method 1]

[image: point in poly method 2]

I imagine determining if a line is inside a polygons is the same checking if both points lie within the polying (so for example if the first point isn't inside the polying, no point in the checking the second).

**Update**
Based on your updated question, here are some images to explain the naive algorithm explained in the comments:

1. find the angle of the line
2. rotate the coordinate system so the line is horizontal
3. check if the shape points (marked green) are above or bellow this (now horizontal) line: above means line is outside, bellow means line is inside

[image: step1]

[image: step2]

I say naive approach because you would check every single shape point in between your line coordinates and I'm not sure how efficient this would be.

A similar approach might be something like this:

1. calculate the angle of the line
2. for each shape point in between your line's start/end points
3. check the angle of the line between the start and current shape point
4. if the angle is smaller the line is outside the shape, exit loop, otherwise, continue testing

Off topic but fun, here's snippet of the idea at the top: testing a line inside poly:

```js
var numPts = 32;
var pts = [];
var hlh = 30;//half line height

function setup(){
  createCanvas(400,400);
  var ai = TWO_PI/numPts;
  for(var i = 0 ; i < numPts ; i++) pts.push(createVector(200+cos(ai*i)*random(100,150),200+sin(ai*i)*random(100,150)));  
}
function draw(){
  background(255);
  fill(0,(lineInPoly(mouseX,mouseY-hlh,mouseX,mouseY-hlh,pts) ? 192 : 0),0);
  beginShape();
  for(var i = 0 ; i < numPts ; i++) vertex(pts[i].x,pts[i].y);
  endShape(CLOSE);
  line(mouseX,mouseY-hlh,mouseX,mouseY+hlh);
}
function pointInPoly(x, y,pts)
{
  var i, j,npol = pts.length;
  var c = false; 
  for (i = 0, j = npol-1; i < npol; j = i++) {
    var p0 = pts[i];
    var p1 = pts[j];
    if ((((p0.y <= y) && (y < p1.y)) ||
         ((p1.y <= y) && (y < p0.y))) &&
        (x < (p1.x - p0.x) * (y - p0.y) / (p1.y - p0.y) + p0.x))
      c = !c;
  }
  return c;
}
function lineInPoly(x1,y1,x2,y2,pts){
  var isFirstInPoly = pointInPoly(x1,y1,pts);
  if(isFirstInPoly){
    return (isFirstInPoly && pointInPoly(x2,y2,pts));
  }else return false;
}
/*
based on Paul Bourke's solution http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonmesh/
int pnpoly(int npol, float *xp, float *yp, float x, float y)
    {
      int i, j, c = 0;
      for (i = 0, j = npol-1; i < npol; j = i++) {
        if ((((yp[i] <= y) && (y < yp[j])) ||
             ((yp[j] <= y) && (y < yp[i]))) &&
            (x < (xp[j] - xp[i]) * (y - yp[i]) / (yp[j] - yp[i]) + xp[i]))
          c = !c;
      }
      return c;
    }
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.7/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I think my question isn't very precise I'll have to describe it differently. Btw I know this approach but let's take the lower one of the two pictures, if the point was lying exactly on the edge of the polygon it's almost impossible to determine if it's really inside or outside - it actually doesn't matter if it actually then should or shouldn't since it is extremely hard as I said

Comment: It makes a bit more sense now. Is there any way you can post a rough diagram/sketch as part of your question ? It might make it easier to fully understand. Thank you

Comment: Hope, it makes more sense now; I really appreciate your effort, the above is for university, the clue with the degrees actually gave me a master student who is currently doing his doctor degree.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are given two points (in this scenario (3,2) and (1,3)) and you want to check if a straight line connecting these points would be inside or outside the given shape. If that is the case, one thing that comes to mind is this: 1. compute the slope of the line. 1. loop through the shape points between your line's start/end coordinates (in this case (1.5,2.5)). and 'un-rotate' agains the line's slope (rotate the points in the opposite direction) so this coordinate system your line would be straight. 3. check if these in between point(s) are above or bellow the line.

Comment: Well, I don't understand where you got that coordinates from^^ but I can understand your approach. So did I get this right that you basically check all points of the conveyor belt that have an x-coordinate that is between the start and the endpoint of the line and check if these points then are all above or below that line. If there are (different) points both below and above the line, the line is inside, yeah?

Comment: You've maked the upper right point as "would be coordinate (3,2)", so I assumed you're coordinate system starts at (1,1) top left. I would've chosen (0,0) :P Anyway, you've got the idea mostly: if all the points in between your line are 'above' the line (y/vertical coordinate is smaller than line's y), that means your line is outside, otherwise, the points would be 'bellow' this line and therefore the line is inside the shape. Note that you would be checking above/bellow the line in the line's coordinate space, not your original coordinate system. I'll post annotated illustrations soon

Comment: I haven't got it with the line's coordinate system yet, but I think I'll understand it with some illustrations, thank you so much :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85478/discussion-between-george-profenza-and-oliver-borchert).